# Push notification not work with production certificate in iphone?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Pushnotification successfully come on my device when i am done with development certificate but  when i am do this using production certificate Push notification not come on my device.

changes i made with production certificate:

1. i create new pem file for server with production certificate
2. i change url to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195'

My push notification send successfully by server but not come on my device whats wrong i made please help.

Comment: plz try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595720/apple-push-notification-not-working-in-production

Comment: Check your certificate

Comment: @Nisar my certificate is correct i am success fully connected using my certificate and message is sent by server site but it not recive on devise i don't know why.and please tell me where to find mobileprovisionfile ?

Comment: Test it here : http://pushmebaby.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Check this out as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872625/push-notification-in-production-mode-is-not-coming-but-in-development-it-is-comi/19887731#19887731

Make sure you installed the adhoc version on your device as well. Development builds cannot receive production certificates.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to get push notification because device token which we receive by development certificate is different one from device token which we get through production certificate.

Device Token (development Certificate) != Device Token (Production Certificate).

So i was trying to use  Device Tokent ( development )  with production Certificate.

Thanks for reply.